# Numpy array trims string values

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the code I am trying to execute

```
matrix = []
sample = [10,10,'mike','']
for i in range(10):
    r = [sample] * 3
    matrix.append(r)

matrix = np.array(matrix)
matrix[1][1] = [123,123,'james', 'sdfsdfsdf werwerwer sdfsdfsd werwerwer sdfsdfsdf']
print matrix[1][1]
```

and here is what I am getting

```
['123' '123' 'james' 'sdfsdfsdf w']
```

so basically the text is trimmed for some reason. Has anyone seen it before?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

conversion from native Python array to Numpy should take place as the last step.

```
matrix[1][1] = [123,123,'james', 'sdfsdfsdf werwerwer sdfsdfsd werwerwer sdfsdfsdf']
matrix = np.array(matrix)
```

Now works fine.

Comment: An array is not a good format for holding a mix of numbers and strings of varying length.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the `dtype` when you are converting your list to an array, it will use default behavior. In your case, you are mixing int's and strings, so it will default to unicode <11:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,'a'])
array(['1', '2', 'a'],
dtype='<U11')
```

When you try to add a new element with a length more than 11, it will truncate to the dtype:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,'a'])
>>> x[2] = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> x
array(['1', '2', 'abcdefghijk'],
      dtype='<U11')
```

You can resolve this by specifying a higher `dtype` when you create the array:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,'a'], '<U50')
>>> x[2] = 'abcdefhijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> x
array(['1', '2', 'abcdefhijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'],
      dtype='<U50')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```
matrix[1][1] = [123,123,'james', 'sdfsdfsdf werwerwer sdfsdfsd werwerwer sdfsdfsdf']
matrix = np.array(matrix)
```

works only because if you do not specify the data type in the array method, numpy set's it to the smallest size possible to hold all data.

If from an interactice python terminal you typed `matrix[1][1]` you would have gotten:

```
array(['123', '123', 'james', 'sdfsdfsdf werwerwer s'], dtype='|S21')
```

The dtype indicates that it's a string of length 21 characters.  Which is why your text get's truncated.  When you implement your array structure, you should provide the dtype if you at some point later want to increase the size of the data.

```
matrix = np.array(matrix, dtype='S50')
matrix[1][1] = [123,123,'james', 'sdfsdfsdf werwerwer sdfsdfsd werwerwer sdfsdfsdf']
print matrix[1][1]

['123' '123' 'james' 'sdfsdfsdf werwerwer sdfsdfsd werwerwer sdfsdfsdf']
```